# Exact sequence that induces exact sequence.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups

Let $M$ be abelian group and $$ A^{'}\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} A \stackrel{g}{\rightarrow} A^{''} \rightarrow 0 $$ an exact sequence of abelian groups. I want to show that 
$$0\rightarrow Hom(A^{''},M)\stackrel{g^*}{\rightarrow}Hom(A,M)\stackrel{f^*}{\rightarrow}Hom(A^{'},M)$$ is also an exact sequence where $f^*(\phi)$ denotes $\phi \circ f$ and $g^*$ the same.

I am having a hard time proving that $im(g^*)=\ker(f^*)$. For every $\phi \in \ker(f^*)$ I tried to construct a group homomorphism $\sigma: A^{\prime \prime} \rightarrow M$ with $\phi=\sigma \circ g$ using the axiom of choice, but I don't think I get a group homomorphism this way. Thank you

Comment: You sequence doesn't end up with $\; A''\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Nope, that is something that confused me, too. It even explicitly only says "exact sequence", instead of short exact sequnce. I think my approach would work, if g was surjective

Comment: That is because the exactness at that point would get lost anyway. That's why you call such a functor $Hom(-,M)$ a *left exact* functor, as it preserves the zero at the left hand side. What I said first hence translates to $Hom(-,M)$ being *left* exact but not exact.

Comment: The functor $\operatorname{Hom}(\cdot,M)$ is contravariant and preserves the $0$ at the *right*-hand side, not at the left-hand side, unless $M$ is injective.

Comment: I don't know much about contravariant functors, does that help me here?

Comment: @Zolf69: Aren't there any hypotheses?

Comment: A contravariant functor reverses  arrowsIt is a basic theorem that, if the given sequence is right exact (i. e. the $0$ is on the right), the Hom sequence is left-exact (the $0$ is on the left).

Comment: I edited the problem, there was a mistake in it. Now I got it to work using the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms.